# Strange screen freezing/hangs

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, intel-graphics, freeze

I have a laptop with hybrid intel/nvidia graphics (core i5 and gt650m).
At random moments the screen, and just the visual part, will freeze/hang. Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to switch the screen & console solves the freeze. when the screen freezes/hangs all the running programs still run and all inputs work as well, it's just the screen that doesn't update.

Any idea as to what could cause this & how to solve it?

---

**Details:**

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 64-bit with the xorg-edgers ppa 340.58 driver (the problem occurs on any driver including nouveau).

The freezes occur at random, at any gpu or cpu usage. My current solution is the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1/7</kbd> switch. Sometimes after switching the screen does not update all the graphics, showing black boxes, moving or interacting with the app solves this.

I haven't made any changes to the xorg config file or nvidia settings program. I'm almost certain that this is not a hardware problem as this problem does not occur in winblows 7.

---

**Edit:** I've been running screen recording software to try to capture the freeze, it did not work, the screen froze twice during the 1.5 hour recording but the recording showed everything as just fine. Apparently this problem only affect what gets sent to the screen. I will try to use a second screen over the hdmi port later.

Comment: Am also seeing this with Linux Mint Rebecca (Trusty) on a similar laptop (intel + geforce graphics, with proprietary Nvidia driver for X). No odd messages in Xorg.0.log, kernel (via dmesg) or .xsession-errors. Console switching unfreezes it same as you. Mystery.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a dual GPU you should use Nvidia-prime or bumblebee to manage them both.

1. Bumblebee allows you to switch between GPUs at a cost of performance
2. Nvidia-Prime allows you to choose what GPU should he use.

you should try both to see if its fixed i would advice nvida prime first to force it using your nvidia.

Comment: The problem occurs somewhat more frequently with bumblebee, it also occurs with Nvidia-Prime on both gpu's.